# how to use popup windows

Tags: android

I want to show a pop up windows which contains various item like shown below:-

```
Path:/mnt/sdcard/absar
Size:100mb
Type:File
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

so if u want statically generate popup msg than just use or call this method where u want to pop up.

```
private void displayDialog(string size,String type){
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(Classname);
        builder.setMessage("Path:"+"/mnt/sdcard/absa" + "\nsize:"+size+ "\ntype:"+type+  )
        .setCancelable(false)
        .setPositiveButton("ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {

            }
        })
        .setNegativeButton("cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                dialog.cancel();                        
            }
        });
        AlertDialog alert = builder.create();   
        alert.setTitle(sethed);
        alert.show();
```

Comment: and if u want for few second popup than use..Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Type ur msg", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 0):

Do look at the documentation for [toast](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/notifiers/toasts.html)